# Error During Upgrading Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: upgrade, sitecore-query

Hi all i'm getting the following Exception while upgrading the instance:

```
6848 07:38:16 FATAL [Experience Analytics]: Failed to synchronize segments. Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..    Details:     at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SegmentUtil.<GetSegmentsToSynchronize>b__0(SegmentDefinition segmentItem)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SegmentUtil.GetSegmentsToSynchronize()
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SegmentUtil.SynchronizeAllSegments()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsProcessor.<Process>d__2.MoveNext()
ManagedPoolThread #3 07:38:18 INFO  Trying to load XML configuration /App_Config/Security/GlobalRoles.config 
ManagedPoolThread #0 07:38:55 INFO  Loading Dictionary from cache
12764 07:38:58 WARN  The "ContentSearch.FullRebuildItemCountThreshold" setting contains an invalid value. The default value is used instead. Invalid value: "". Default value: "100000"
ManagedPoolThread #9 07:39:13 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_core_index
6252 07:39:14 WARN  The "ConcurrentMergeSchedulerThreads" setting contains an invalid value. The default value is used instead. Invalid value: "". Default value: "25"
ManagedPoolThread #9 07:39:32 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_core_index (units processed: )
```

Comment: Have you tried to deploy Marketing Definitions?

Comment: i'm not able to deploy marketing definitions.Im getting this message: There was an error deploying the definitions. Consult the Sitecore logs for more information.

Comment: Please provide the error in the question. Check the Sitecore logs and post the error here

Comment: Please provide more details as steps followed for upgradation

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the the Marketing Definition has been deployed. First, please check if the workflow of the Marketing Definition items are set to deployed (see screenshot below). Path: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics`

[image]

Once you see that all the definition items have the proper workflow state, go to the Sitecore Control Panel and click on the Deploy Marketing Definition

[image]